# (ERROR: internal) Testing Firebase functions using React Native Expo

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, expo

I'm trying to test my firebase functions in my React Native Expo app. Here's my initialization code:

```
import { connectFunctionsEmulator, getFunctions } from 'firebase/functions'

// ...Initialize app 

export const fucntions = getFunctions()
connectFunctionsEmulator(fucntions, "localhost", 5001)
```

I then have code which maps functions in an object:

```
import { httpsCallable } from "firebase/functions";
import { fucntions } from "../../firebase";

export default {
    helloFirebase: httpsCallable(fucntions, "helloFirebase")
}
```

And I call the function as follows:

```
functionsObj.helloFirebase({ myParam: "Hello!" })
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message)
    })
```

But when I call the function I get the following, very small and unspecific error message in the console:

```
ERROR: internal
```

I'm guessing it's something to do with not being able to access localhost, but I still don't know how to fix the issue.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXED: I found this article on [this](https://dev.to/haydenbleasel/using-the-firebase-local-emulator-with-expo-s-managed-workflow-5g5k) exact issue.

Make sure to run `firebase serve --only functions -o ${YOUR_LOCAL_IP}` once you've followed all the steps